# splitting a column by factor within a data frame

Tags: r, split, dataframe, plyr

Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```
v1   v2   v3
a    1    a
a    2    b
a    6    c
b    3    a
b    4    b
b    5    c
```

Where v1 is a factor, and v3 is a character. I want to apply some function to the data frame such v2 is split across v1 and then included in the data frame:

```
v1   v2   v3   v4   v5
a    1    a    1    NA
a    2    b    2    NA
a    6    c    6    NA
b    3    a    NA   3
b    4    b    NA   4
b    5    c    NA   5
```

The solutions I have been able to work out are very convoluted. Is there an elegant way of doing this?

(Note: v3 exists because any solution needs to be able to deal with the existence of other non-numeric vectors in the data frame that should be ignored.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1) transform / ifelse** A simple approach if there are a small known number of values in `v1` is to manually generate each new column:

```
transform(DF, a = ifelse(v1 == "a", v2, NA), 
              b = ifelse(v1 == "b", v2, NA))
```

**2) tapply** A more general approach would be:

```
cbind(DF, tapply(DF$v2, list(1:nrow(DF), DF$v1), identity))
```

The solutions above do not require any addon packages.

**3) data.table**.  This solution assumes that `v1` is a factor and that the rows of `DF` are unique (as is the case in the question):

```
# devtools::install_github("Rdatatable/datatable")  # 1.9.3

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(DF)

DT[, split(v2, v1), by = DT]
```

If the rows of `DT` might not be unique then (based on discussion with Arun) this would work:

```
DT[, c(.SD, split(v2, v1)), by = 1:nrow(DT)][, -1, with = FALSE]
```

**Update** Some improvements.

Answer (score 3):

Using `dplyr` 
If `dd` is the dataset

```
# install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("hadley/tidyr")
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
dd1 <- dd %>% 
  mutate(n = seq_len(n())) %>%
  spread(v1,v2) %>% 
  arrange(n) %>% 
  select(-n,-v3)

cbind(dd, dd1)
#    v1 v2 v3  a  b
#1  a  1  a  1 NA
#2  a  2  b  2 NA
#3  a  6  c  6 NA
#4  b  3  a NA  3
#5  b  4  b NA  4
#6  b  5  c NA  5
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the `reshape2` package here. First, your test data

```
dd<-data.frame(
    v1 = factor(c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b")),
    v2 = c(1, 2, 6, 3, 4, 5), 
    v3 = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"),
    stringsAsFactors=F
)
```

and now create the new columns

```
library(reshape2)
nc<-dcast(dd, 1:nrow(dd)~v1, value.var="v2")[-1]
```

and now merge them in

```
dd<-cbind(dd, nc)
dd
```

to get

```
  v1 v2 v3  a  b
1  a  1  a  1 NA
2  a  2  b  2 NA
3  a  6  c  6 NA
4  b  3  a NA  3
5  b  4  b NA  4
6  b  5  c NA  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Gabor's `data.table` answer is nice, but it `split`s on each row, which can get slow on bigger tables. Here's another way using `rbindlist`, from [1.9.3](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table) though:

```
tmp = DT[, list(V = list(
             setattr(list(v2), 'names', v1)
           )), by = list(v1 = as.character(v1))]$V
## 1.9.3
tmp = rbindlist(tmp, fill=TRUE)
#     a  b
# 1:  1 NA
# 2:  2 NA
# 3:  6 NA
# 4: NA  3
# 5: NA  4
# 6: NA  5

DT[, c(names(tmp)) := tmp]
#    v1 v2 v3  a  b
# 1:  a  1  a  1 NA
# 2:  a  2  b  2 NA
# 3:  a  6  c  6 NA
# 4:  b  3  a NA  3
# 5:  b  4  b NA  4
# 6:  b  5  c NA  5
```

PS: This solution assumes that `DT` is sorted on column `v1`.

---

Here's another version where it doesn't depend on `v1` being sorted:

```
for (j in unique(DT$v1)) {
    ix = which(DT$v1 == j)
    set(DT, i=ix, j=j, value=DT$v2[ix])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach with base, which does the job directly:

```
n <- ncol(x)
for (i in 1:length(levels(x$v1))) 
{
    s <- as.numeric(x$v1)==i
    x[s,n+i] <- x$v2[s]
}

> x
  v1 v2 v3 V4 V5
1  a  1  a  1 NA
2  a  2  b  2 NA
3  a  6  c  6 NA
4  b  3  a NA  3
5  b  4  b NA  4
6  b  5  c NA  5
```

This is taking the numeric value of the factor `x$v1` and using that as the position to which to copy the data from `v2`.  As it is adding columns, it doesn't matter what else might be present.